# Google Analytics verification failure but we're still seeing the data

Tags: google-analytics, site-verification

Today I saw this in Google Search Console:

[image]

This clearly says the Google Analytics verification failed. But we have all the info, charts, real online users, etc... in the Google Analytics panel. So what might be the cause of that error?

Also, we've added Google Analytics inside Google Tag manager and put that script inside the `head` of our website:

[image]

Any idea of what might be the source of this error?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it failed verification as a means of verifying site ownership in Google Search Console.
This does not mean the GA tracking is not installed and working, just that the current method of installation, cant be used to verify site ownership.

If GA is setup via tags in GTM, then GA cannot be used for verification. it needs to be the GA tracking code snippet installed in the site between the `<head></head>` tags.

You can use GTM container to verify Google Search Console site ownership instead.

Comment: Ah upvote .. just to be honest, I'm not a SEO expert and I don't understand what happened now exactly .. should I do something specific or all fine now ?

Comment: You're already verified via GTM, HTML file upload and HTML Tag. No need to do anything futher.